# Sending Filebeat logs to AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis, filebeat

## My Problem

I have a log pipeline in which logs are written to files and shipped to ElasticSearch using [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-overview.html). I would like to switch from ElasticSearch to AWS Kinesis, and I wonder what's the right way to configure Filebeat for the new output.

## My Options

- Google for a solution - found [`kinesisbeat`](https://github.com/bwarminski/kinesisbeat), but it is not very well documented or used.
- Running a custom script using the [exec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-exec.html). However, since "The exec output will run a command for each event received", it is impractical for high volume log streams.
- Writing my own plugin. Possible, but I would not like to reinvent the wheel.

## My Question

How do I send logs from Filebeat to AWS Kinesis?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, I'm currently looking at the firehose java agent  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html

Comment: I am working on a custom output for Firehose & Kinesis for filebeat, but requires compling from source since they do not accept new plugins anymore

Comment: @Sergey Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @AdamMatan, ok, posted as an answer and deleted the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check https://github.com/s12v/awsbeats, which I'm working on at the moment. However, it requires Go 1.10 which is still a RC.

Comment: Perfect. Please update your answer when it's fully functional.